# Как объединить результаты select если выполняется условие?

Tags: sql

Всем привет. У меня есть такой скрипт:

```sql
SELECT [Матчи].Дата as Дата,
        [Команда].Группа as Группа,
      [Команда].Страна as Страна,
      [Матчи].Id_Матча as Id,
      COUNT ([Голы].Id_Матча) as Голы
  FROM [Команда] INNER JOIN [Матчи]
  ON [Команда].Id = [Матчи].Id_команды
  INNER JOIN [Голы]
  ON [Команда].Id = [Голы].Id_Команды AND [Голы].Id_Матча = [Матчи].Id_Матча
  WHERE [Дата] = '25.06.2018'
    GROUP BY [Матчи].Id_Матча, [Матчи].Дата, [Команда].Страна, [Команда].Группа, [Команда].Id
  ORDER BY [Матчи].Id_Матча, Голы DESC
```

Структура таблиц:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И есть результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня такой вопрос, как я могу объединить две строки, например, Уругвай и Россия, если id их матча совпадает, и соответственно вывести Уругвай - Россия, 2-1, что-то в таком духе?

Comment: СУБД-то укажите хотя бы...

Comment: MICROSOFT SQL 17

Comment: Добавьте в запрос ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_матча), засуньте весь запрос в CTE, там объедините пары записей по равенству id_матча и конкатенируйте кейсами.

Comment: А можно пример как это можно сделать, просто я новичок в SQL, и эти запросы для меня уже выглядят немного сложно